# Routing in angular2 with Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-routing, angular

I'm new to Angular2, till now I got succeeded to write the [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/quickstart.html).

I want to learn how to use routing in **Angular2** and **Dart**, unfortunately I couldn't find any example on the web yet. most of the articles are talking about routing with typescript which I couldn't get it work with dart.

*I'm using webstorm with dart plugin.*

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/bootstrap.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';

@Component(selector: 'my-app', template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>')
class AppComponent {}

void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

Comment: I can't see how the code you posted is related to routing. Do you have a concrete TypeScript example you want to make work in Dart?

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0
Can you convert this to dart? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: If you already tried to port this to Dart yourself please provide a GitHub example and add some information to your question where you're stuck or what error you get.

Comment: I can't make syntax myself otherwise I wouldn't post this question! I want a general and simple using of routing in dart, nothing specific @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is only for specific questions. I didn't ask for a working Dart port but you should demonstrate some effort to solve the problem yourself and then provide a reproducible example that demonstrates your problem. This isn't a give me some code site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this HashLocationStrategy example.

https://github.com/ng2-dart-samples/todomvc

Answer (score 2):

I found [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) quite helpful to set up routing in my application.